# NetSuite - How to get Subsidiary preferences

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am using SuiteScript to fetch Subsidiary information. Using nlapiLookupField method I am able to see the basic fields. But I want some information on Subsidiary-Preferences tab.

It seems nlapiLookupField cannot access fields on a subtab (Preferences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fields are not even listed in [SuiteScript Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2013_1/index.html).

One way to read them is by loading the record eg:

```
   var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('subsidiary', 11);
   rec.getFieldValue('CHECKTYPE');
```

Comment: Right. Since they're not listed in the Records Browser, they are most likely not available for lookup/searching. The fields I see when loading the record are:
- CALENDARSYSTEM
- CHECKTYPE
- CUSTCENTEREMAILTEMPLATE
- DATEFORMAT
- EMAILACCESSTEMPLATE
- LONGDATEFORMAT
- NEGATIVE_NUMBER_FORMAT
- NUMBERFORMAT
- PARTCENTEREMAILTEMPLATE
- PHONEFORMAT
- SPELL_LOCALE
- TIMEFORMAT
- TIMEZONE

Comment: Does that mean that I should load the record first and then using getFieldValue function load that field??

Comment: @azeem Yes, This is the only way I know of

Answer (score 1):

Open the record inside the NetSuite UI. Append '&xml=T' to the end of the url for the record.

Take a look at the underlying XML data - that should be everything you see in the UI, and you will see the field names, sublists, etc.