# How to get netsuite user, role, subsidiary & company preferences via suitescript APIs?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In Netsuite account we have four preferences,

- User Preferences
- Role Preferences
- Subsidiary Preferences
- Company Preferences

**According to this reference :** https://<>.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N243257.html

Are there any suitescipt APIs to get these four preferences seperately?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

User and Company: You can start by checking the N/config module.

Subsidiary: Check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568348/netsuite-how-to-get-subsidiary-preferences).